# Change the class loader of the JSP servlet (Jasper)

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat, servlets

What I want to achieve, is to proxy the request URI and render a different JSP file depending on some condition in the request users session.

I.e.

userA -> request: /{container}/index.jsp -> return: {viewA}/index.jsp

userB -> request: /{container}/index.jsp -> return: {viewB}/index.jsp

Servlet filters don't have enough control to do this sort of thing.
What I'd imagine would work would be to override the URLClassLoader of the JSPServlet so that I can search for the file [in a custom classloader] to be compiled.  Is this possible, or is there another way?

I read something that relates to what I'm trying to acheive here: http://www.softwaresummit.com/2003/speakers/BergmanTomcat.pdf pp 10, however, it doesn't really appear to work (extending HttpJspBase doesn't give you anything).

I've tried to illustrate the flow in this [rather poor] image:

http://80.68.91.73/pageflow.png

I'm more looking for a steer in the right direction rather than a complete solution.  The problem is, I can't find the right keywords to find what I'm looking for!

Thanks!

John

Answer (score 0):

This is not exactly what you asked for, but have you considered having only one index.jsp and use the forward-tag to forward the request to different sub-pages?

```
<% if(session.someCondition) { %>
  <jsp:forward page="index-version1.jsp"/>
<% } else { %>
  <jsp:forward page="index-version2.jsp"/>
<% } %>
```

You may also forward the request from a servlet filter using something like this:

```
FilterConfig filterConfig;

public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    this.filterConfig = filterConfig;
}

public void doFilter( ..) {

    filterConfig.getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(<insert path to correct version of your page here>).forward(request, response);

}
```

If you don't want the jsp-pages to be accessible directly, you may store them in different sub-directories below WEB-INF. That way, you may forward to them, but they can't be reached directly from the web.

Comment: It's not just index.jsp that is duplicated (it could be 100 pages).  Each different affilliate will have a completely different design (but with one common codebase).